# Telephony Service Provider

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, telephony

I want to develop new TSP (Telephony Service Provider) for CTI Application that will work with my Hardware.

For that I have used C++ Language & Visual Studio 2010.

I have understood the Working flow of TSP with TAPI Application using TSPI interface.

For complete package to be installed in Windows XP i need one ".DLL" file to export TSPI function for TAPISRV.EXE. For that it should be put in system32 folder in Windows.

Other Fle is ".tsp" that is also need to be put in system32 folder that is needed to add my TSP is Phone & Modem option in Control panel in Window Xp. But i am not sure.

By exploring i didn't found any good stuff about this file.

I just know that ".tsp" is telephony service provider file.

So can anyone tell me that,
What is that ".tsp" file & is it executable or anything else ?
Why it is required ?
How to build ".tsp" file in visual studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Actually ".tsp" file is just replaced extension of ".DLL" file.
Thus ".DLL" file is itself ".tsp" file.

So ".tsp" file is dynamic link library & i need only one file to be put in system32 folder that is ".tsp" file.